# Using Solr DataImportHandler for updating documents

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

In simple usage Solr DataImportHandler deletes old document and replace it with new. Is it possible to use DataImportHandler for updating only part of existing document fields and left other intact? I want to do second data import for part of fields, which will use light SQL queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link would help you to resolve the issue.

Look at http://solr.pl/en/2012/07/09/solr-4-0-partial-documents-update/

Comment: This will work, but this is not with DataImportHandler, and require creating custom script for updating this data.

Comment: oh.ok.Partial updates not support for DIH in solr.Try with SolrJ.